# Custom headers ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webdav, caldav, custom-headers

I'm trying to serve WebDav requests to create a CalDav server so that users can access our calendar function easily on any device of their choosing.

The problem is in trying to serve any custom headers. I've written a custom ActionResult that sets up any result easily in the right way. Upon a OPTIONS request, which gets recognized, it adds:

```
response.AppendHeader("Allow", "OPTIONS, PROPFIND, HEAD, GET, REPORT, PROPPATCH, PUT, DELETE, POST");
```

When I look into the request that the end-user receives the following header appears:

```
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
```

When I then try to do a request with the custom header `PROPFIND` it simply returns a 404 error. I tried googling but there is not a lot around about this stuff. It's probably something I have to enable or disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `WebDavModule` and `WebDav` handler in the web config. After I had done that it worked perfectly.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. The most essential part is how does your action method talk "webDAV" to requests clients. How do you go about serving/fulfilling webDAV requests? Can you give me some resources I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

please see section How To.
You can do it on multiple ways

- IIS
- Web.Config
- Code : C#, VB.NET, JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not really what I meant. I've written a custom `ActionResult` which gets returned when any action completes. Upon the completion of a request with the `OPTIONS` header it returns the possible headers plus some XML data. But I think MVC is overwriting the `Allow` header after the action completes.